# Wordpress custom post type pagination to only show those with custom field checked

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've been trying to figure this out for the past day or so but I'm coming up short!

I have a custom post type called Case Studies. Inside a case study is a custom field called 'featured_case_study' which is a true/false field. If the user checks the box it will make the case study 'featured'.

Once I'm inside a featured case study post I'd like to use pagination to move to the next featured case study. At the moment my pagination includes ALL my case studies, but I'd only like it to paginate between the featured ones.

I've been trying all sorts of different methods but I can't seem to figure this one out. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: where does your 'featured_case_study' gets stored at? In your database? Cookies? Or?

Comment: I would have thought in the database.. I've created the custom field using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Comment: "If the user checks the box it will make the case study", then are you talking about a user with access to dashboard? or a website visitor?

Comment: Sorry, let me clear that up! The admin will go into the dashboard to create a case study post. Inside the case study post there is a checkbox. When checked it will make the post Featured.

Comment: ah now I see! Ok I am coming up with something that'd roughly answer you, in a min!

Answer (score 1):

You must first find out where your pagination codes are (depending on the plugin you are using for it), and then:

```
$pageID = get_the_ID(); //get the post ID of the current post

if (the_field("featured_case_study", $pageID) == "true")
{
// then the same code as the rest of the pagination, copy it in!
//Only, when it comes to next and previous, you must emphasis AGAIN that

if (the_field("featured_case_study", $NextPageID) == "true")
//then have it linked as next

if (the_field("featured_case_study", $PreviousPageID) == "true")
//then have it linked as previous
}
```

Comment: Sorry if it's a general answer, your question is relatively general too, hence I can't talk code much :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I think I understand where you're trying to go with it.. but I couldn't figure it out (I'm a bit of a beginner with PHP). In the end I used a plugin (Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus) where I was able to select a custom field to filter by.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out :) Enjoy coding!